# SQL Unique on join

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have an application where:

1. User has many applications
2. Application has 3 different documents(one table per document). Application can have more than one document of each kind in some cases.

I need to be able to

1. A user can have only one "approved" application at any point - Achieved
2. No document can be re-used across multiple applications belonging to 2 different users.

I am stuck on how to go about requirement 2.

Current Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE applications (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    status character varying(255) DEFAULT 'pending'::character varying NOT NULL,
    active boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    email character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT applications_status_values CHECK (((status)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['pending'::character varying, 'approved'::character varying, 'rejected'::character varying, 'archived'::character varying])::text[])))
);
```

An example of a document kind:

```
CREATE TABLE pan (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    value character(10) NOT NULL,
    status document_statuses DEFAULT 'pending'::document_statuses,
    extra_data json,
    verified_at timestamp without time zone,
    reject_reason character varying,
    application_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Maybe the data model will help to clarify how to achieve that.
For example, do you have the user owner on each document table?

Comment: @Maik I have user_id on application. Each document kind has application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look to your model I think there is a concept error.

You say: No document can be re-used across multiple applications belonging to 2 different users

So, this in other terms is that the document only can be re-used in any other app if the user is the same. So, we can go a high level and understant that each document has a user_owner, and while this document is used by this user all is correct.

Then, what I suggest is the simple solution:

```
ALTER TABLE pan ADD COLUMN user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES user (user_id);
```

And then Update this field with the correct value. This will simplify your solution and also add a reference to the user that generated the document.

**EDIT:**

Add this trigger, thills will call a procedure with the update sentence:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER t_document_owner
    AFTER UPDATE ON applications 
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.user_id IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.user_id) 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE p_update_document_owner(NEW.user_id,OLD.user_id);
```

This is a basic proposal for the update procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION p_update_document_owner(new_user_id,old_user_id) RETURNS VOID
AS
'
UPDATE pan 
SET user_id=$1
WHERE user_id = 
(SELECT user_id 
 FROM (
      SELECT user_id 
      FROM pan WHERE      
      user_id=$2
      )as aux
)
'LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: The issue is that the application can be assigned to a different user. So the user_owner can change. I originally designed the models for using a user_id but with the requirement of being able to change the user of an "application" I had to introduce a proxy layer "application_id"

Comment: @Amit why do not use triggers?

Comment: I haven't used those before. How would I go about using them, from a design. I can read about the implementation

Comment: @Amit Basically triggers are another DDBB tool. This will apply some persistent action into the database before or after a certain operation.

In this case you would use the sentence that I attach to my previous response.